# how to prevent sensitive data showing in heap memory using Javascript

Tags: javascript, heap-memory

I have a web application in asp.net-mvc and I am using Javascript in front end the problem is when I log in into my web application the password is getting stored in heap memory of google chrome

below is the screenshot for the same

[image]

I tried the below options:

1. encode the password before the login ajax call - but didn't worked
2. Emptied thepassword textbox before the login ajax call - but didn't worked

how can I clear the password from heap memory, below is the snapshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: are you retaining any references to password? explicitly set all these to null, this could force garbage collection. also, how are you generating password? as primitive type in js don't imagine string would be retained in heap, although I see the reference to concatenated string

Comment: Thanks @GregBrodzik .It worked for me. Appreciate your timely support.